# What's wrong with my jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to periodically refresh a .Net view.
I get **Missing ] after element list error**
Here's my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    window.setInterval(loadRings(), 5000);
});
    function loadRings() {
    $.ajax({
            url: "Rings/Index",
            context: document.body,
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#ajaxDiv").html(msg);
            }
        });
    }
```

Any idea what's going on?

**UPDATE:**
The setInterval should be

> window.setInterval(loadRings, 5000);

Comment: I'm not sure that error comes from this code...

Comment: Not sure why you gave -1, I told up there in bold the error I am getting

Comment: I didn't give you a -1, and you didn't address my comment. Whatever tool is showing you that error probably tells you where the error came from.

Comment: Sorry about that. I am not sure but the error came in the line starting with success:....   . It is fixed though.

Comment: If it's fixed you should write the answer and mark that solution as accepted. We're building a repository of questions and answers here, not just helping individuals like yourself. Make this page useful for others.

Comment: Done. I just realized you were the first one to answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
window.setInterval(loadRings(), 5000);
```

should be

```
window.setInterval(loadRings, 5000);
```

Answer (score 6):

`setInterval` accepts a function reference. However, you are manually executing the function. Try:

```
window.setInterval( loadRings, 5000 );
```

Answer (score 4):

```
window.setInterval(loadRings(), 5000);
```

you must pass the reference to a function, but you're making a function call there.

like this:

```
window.setInterval(loadRings, 5000);
```